# Tag synonym: logon -> login

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I proposed this a little bit ago, but with the way the tag synonym voting system works (or not) and how well it's hidden anyway, it seems much more useful to just propose it here and have a mod push it through, I think.

[So please, push through the suggested synonym](https://serverfault.com/tags/login/synonyms): [logon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/logon) -> [login](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/login).

Answer (score 1):

Yep... The system is borked, just post here if you find such tags.